# Serialize and deserialize XML, same root node, different content

Tags: xml, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, xml-deserialization

I'm setting up a web service and the client has specified request and response format (XML). The issue is that they all have the same root node, but the content varies. I have been searching a lot, but not been able to find any solution that works both ways. It doesn't help that I'm new to this.

Some examples (There are around 10 in total, all with the same root.)

Requests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<message id="123" company="CompanyA">
    <query>
        <product>someProduct</product>
        <dateFrom>2012-01-01</dateFrom>
        <dateTo>2012-01-10</dateTo> 
        <status>10</status> 
    </query>
</message>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<message id="456" company="CompanyB">
    <query>
        <price>99.95</price>
        <quantity>50</quantity> 
    </query>
</message>
```

Response:

```
<message Id="789" company="CompanyC">
    <file>
        <fileName>abc123.pdf</fileName>
        <data>LLSHDFLJHSJKLDFHJLKS</data>           
    </file>
</message>
```

I've created different objects to deserialize to and set the name using XmlRoot, but I get a conflict unless I use namespace as well. Is there any simple way around this? The closest solution is to rename using XmlRoot and namespace, but the client doesn't want the namespace.

```
[DataContract, XmlRoot("message")]
public class Message
{
   [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
   public string id { get; set; }
   [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
   public string company { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedMessage:Message
{
   [DataMember, XmlElement]
   public string whantEver { get; set; }       
}

public class ExtendedMessage2:Message
{
   [DataMember, XmlElement]
   public int someNumber { get; set; }       
}
```

I'm using C# (ASP.NET MVC 4).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you have problem deserializing xml into objects?

Comment: Yes, I have several classes for the different requests/responses, but I can't name them all "message" so I tried [XmlElement(ElementNamw= "message") but unless I add namespace as well I get conflicts, and the client doesn't want namespace.

Comment: why don't you simply extract the values from the xml requests using XDocument or XmlDocument? then you don't need any serialization classes

Comment: I was told not to. But maybe we need to do something different.

Comment: who told you that? what is the explanation? is the reason performance? if yes then there are light weight xml parsers

Comment: We needed to use a current solution with minimum changes. We solved it by switching to JSON.